# How can I generate HTML documentation for a SOAP/WebService class in .Net?

Tags: .net, soap, wsdl

When you start a WebService project in VisualStudio(VS) you do actually see some HTML documentation, but the C# comment help does not make it across to the HTML. You can get a description to come through for each web method by using the Description property of the WebMethod attribute, however this means duplicating text from the comment help and also doesn't allow for documenting web method arguments as far as I can tell.

Is there an easy way of picking up the comment help already present in C# code?

Thankyou.

Comment: That's why there are vote buttons!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now use WCFExtra library to convert XML comments in my code into documentation comments in the WSDL.

From there we use TechWriter to build the documentation.

Comment: Don't write comments as answers please.

Answer (score 1):

The C# comments don't get compiled into the assembly. There's a [solution over at Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/webservicedoc.aspx) for providing alternate WSDL documentation: it shouldn't be too difficult to set up an ASP.NET application to read the raw xml documentation file, with some configuration to match WSDL services and operations to classes and methods.

I don't know if there are any off-the-shelf solutions for your problem, though.